# Merge two tables with UNIQUE Key into another table and add the key in the resulting table after the merge

Tags: mysql, myisam

I would like to merge two very large MyISAM tables (with the same structure) and a unique key on 3 columns. Is it possible to create the table where they are going to be merged WITHOUT the unique key, merge the tables' contents, and only then add the unique key in the resulting table, with the effect of ON DUPLCATE KEY UPDATE another field? So, to summarize, I have:

```
Table 1 - Fields f1,f2,f3,f4 (Unique Key on f1,f2,f3)
Table 2 - Fields f1,f2,f3,f4 (Unique Key on f1,f2,f3)
Table 3 - Where Table 1 and Table 2 will be merged, 
          with fields f1,f2,f3,f4 and NO unique key.
```

So then I want to merge Table 1 and 2 into Table 3 and only after the merge is complete, I want to add a unique key (f1,f2,f3) on Table 3 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f4=f4+1...(i.e. The result desired is that of INSERTing rows from Table 1 and Table 2 into Table 3 (with a preexisting unique key on f1,f2,f3) and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f4=f4+1 but creating the key in Table 3 only after all the Table 1 and Table 2 rows have been inserted). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
INSERT INTO Table3
       (f1, f2, f3, f4)
SELECT  f1, f2, f3, f4
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.f1, t2.f2, t2.f3, CASE t1.f1 IS NOT NULL THEN t2.f4 + 1 ELSE t2.f4 END 
FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.f1 = t2.f1 AND t1.f2 = t2.f2 AND t1.f3 = t2.f3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Would this scale well when table 1 and table 2 have about 80 million rows each, considering that you are using a union and a left join? Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping this is an off task that you had to do once but if it's not I am not sure what solution would be faster (or how much faster), I'll post a second solution in 2 steps but I'll leave it up to you to test them and decide which one is faster

Answer (score 0):

Second solution in 2 steps

```
INSERT INTO Table3
       (f1, f2, f3, f4)
SELECT  f1, f2, f3, f4
FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT  f1, f2, f3, f4
FROM Table2

UPDATE Table3
SET f4 = f4 + 1
FROM Table3
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT f1,f2,f3, COUNT(f4) Cnt
      FROM Table3
      GROUP BY f1,f2,f3
      HAVING COUNT(f4) >= 2 ) t ON Table3.f1 = t.f1 AND Table3.f2 = t.f2
             AND Table3.f3 = t.f3
```

P.S. I Believe that the first solution with the left join is faster